# Is this design in 3NF? Why to choose another design not in 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have entities `Objects`, `Parts`, `Subparts` and `Items` and the following restrictions:

- A `Part` belongs to one and only one `Object`.
- A `Subpart` belongs to one and only one `Part`.
- An `Item` belongs to one and only one `Subpart`.

I have implemented the following tables (primary keys marked with *):

- `Object` (*IDObject)
- `Part` (*IDPart, *IDObject): IDObject is a foreign key (the primary key of `Object`)
- `Subpart` (*IDSubpart, *IDPart, *IDObject): *IDPart, *IDObject is a foreign key (the primary key of `Part`)
- `Item` (*IDItem, *IDSubpart, *IDPart, *IDObject): IDSubpart, IDPart, IDObject is a foreign key (the primary key of `Subpart`)

Is this design is in 3NF?

`Item` is a [weak entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) depending on `Subpart`, `Subpart` is a weak entity depending on `Part`, and `Part` is a weak entity depending on `Object`, so by theory we get those composite keys, making this design in 3NF.

But for other people, this design is redundant, and the best way for resolving it is through the following tables (primary keys marked with *):

- `Object` (*IDObject)
- `Part` (*IDPart, IDObject): IDObject is a foreign key, but doesn't make part of the primary key of `Part`
- `Subpart` (*IDSubpart, IDPart): IDPart is a foreign key, but doesn't make part of the primary key of `Subpart`
- `Item` (*IDItem, IDSubpart): IDSubpart is a foreign key, but doesn't make part of the primary key of `Item`

In this specification, the restrictions of "one and only one" would be managed by code.

Why would I choose this implementation, declining to use 3NF?

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both** designs are technically 3NF, depending on your data population.

What a lot of people who have only a cursory understanding of formal normalization theory don't understand is that redundancy in foreign keys isn't really redundancy *by definition*.  Transitive dependencies and partial dependencies apply to the way *non-key* attributes relate to *key* attributes.

If your composite keys happen to contain (or even consist of) foreign keys then whether your foreign key has the look of being denormalized isn't relevant.  (i.e. Design 1 isn't redundant in a way which is significant to the formal definition of normal forms.)

The *practical* issue comes down to what the **values** of your keys are.  If you have natural keys and the `Part` key consists of `IDObject`=123 and `IDPart`=1 - i.e. your IDPart values are natural number sequences which are only unique within the context of a given IDObject value, then you **need** to use design 1 (weak entities).

However, what a lot of people do for good (and less good) reasons is apply *surrogate primary keys* to every or nearly every table.  I'm not going to get into *whether* or *why* to use surrogate keys.  That is a holy war for another question.  However, *if* you happen to have table-wide unique (e.g. IDENTITY) values for IDPart, then your primary key for `Part` is more complex than it needs to be using design 1.  In that case, there is no need for `IDObject` in the PK of `Part` because the table already has a unique key just using `IDPart`.  In such a case, design 2 is sufficient and simpler, therefore better, as a rule of thumb.

In practice, I would say weak entities are much more common in logical models than in physical models, if for no other reason than that most physical models tend to use surrogate primary keys.

Comment: The answer is very valuable for its clarity and completeness, by involving several key concepts about the logical modeling and physical implementation of a database.

Comment: What can be said about normalization when replacing the composite natural key of a logic N to M relationship by a subrogate key?

Comment: @villamejia - Adding a single surrogate key to the intersection entity that implements a logical M:N is a difficult case.  To answer your question directly, it is not a subject for _normalization_ per se.  There may be practical reasons for doing this, especially in the physical model and especially if the relationship itself is a parent of some third entity.  However, I think it is often seen simply because some people dogmatically apply surrogate keys to every table in their database.